# HyperV network dropouts during file copy to/from NAS

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, hyper-v, rdp

The problem I am having is that it seems like any network traffic on a guest virtual machine locks out RDP access to all guest instances and to the host.

For example, if I initiate a file copy from my NAS to a guest via RDP, as soon as the file copy starts, my RDP session gets dropped. At this point, I can no longer RDP or ping any of the guests nor can I get into the host server.

When the file copy completes, access is immediately restored.

My configuration is:

- Windows Server 2008 R2
- Dell 2900, 18g RAM, Dual NICs, only one is hooked up though
- Guests instances are also Server 2008 R2 using the same NIC as the host
- Gigabit switch
- NAS is a Synology DX1511+

My first thought is that I should not be using one NIC for both the guests and the host. What is the recommended configuration?

My second thought is that I need to look at the NIC card for some sort of issue. I don't see anything in the event viewer.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is usually better to have a network adapter for the guests external network that is separate from the Hyper-V host.

Also, on the guests, you should verify the following network adapter > advanced settings:

- Jumbo packet: Disabled
- Large Send Offload (IPV4): Disabled
- Large Send Offload (IPV6): Disabled